# I tried making a custom axe and the geometry is weird

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, topology, artifacts

I tried to make an axe based off of a reference image from google and the geometry is weird and showing many artefacts after applying subdivision surface.

I eliminated all doubles using merge by distance and also the entire geometry is in quads. I feel that there is some close lines and I tried merging a few shapes but I can't figure out what.

I am new at blender and I realize that the geometry is bad so asking for your help.

Here is the blend file

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14xmpw7HWBSs5hGiOXNs609RYpnqFPbZg?usp=sharing

Comment: the only weird thing I see is this vertex, delete it and fill the faces it will leave: https://zupimages.net/up/21/40/mzlt.jpg

Comment: @moonboots Yea that is one, but deleting that vertices messes up the face below and above it... I don't know how to tackle that. Also there are a lot of artifacts at the place where the blade joins the cylinder.

Comment: yes there's a problem here, there's a face that you need to delete, then again fill the faces: https://zupimages.net/up/21/40/9mgs.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit mode:

- Enter Face select mode
- Select and delete this face:

[image: face to delete]

- Select and delete these faces:

[image: more faces to delete]

- Select and delete this vertex:

[image: Vertex to delete]

- Enter Edge select mode
- Using the F2 add-on fill the large hole with faces:

[image: hole filled with 10 faces]

F2 allows you to select one edge of the hole, position the cursor inside the hole and then create the face with <kbd>F</kbd>.  Select the left most edge of the hole, position the cursor to the right of it, and type <kbd>F</kbd> ten times.  This is fewer key strokes than filling the individual holes.

- Select the 4 edges of the left hole and add a face with <kbd>F</kbd>:

[image: left hole to file]

- Use F2 to fill the right hole.
- The easiest way (at least to describe) to deal with the rest is:
- select all of the edges surrounding the remaining hole and make an n-gon face:

[image: n-gon to finish filling the hole.]

- Finally, use the knife tool to subdivide the N-gon into six quad with three cuts:

[image: the final six faces]

You might want to edge slide vertices to smooth out the new lowest row of faces.

By the way, you have a similar but slightly different problem on the other side of the axe.  If you deselect all and then use the Select menu to *Select All by Trait* -> *Non-Manifold*  you'll find the problem:

[image: issues on the back]

[image]

Comment: I did solve the problem....These were some elementary problems.... But thanks a lot for solving it.